# Cart ui not loading data after reload although data are in local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, cart, react-fullstack

I'm encountering an issue where a cart UI isn't loading data after a reload, even though the data is stored in local storage. I'm stranded on this can one help me on this have tried troubleshooting the error but have not succedded .... Here below are some codes cart.js ui and my reducers and actions for the cart state

cart.js (UI)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { RxCross1 } from "react-icons/rx";
import { IoBagHandleOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import { HiOutlineMinus, HiPlus } from "react-icons/hi";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "../../../styles/style";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from "../../../redux/actions/cart";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
// import EmptyCart from "../../../assets/images/emptyCart.png";
import EmptyCart from "../../../assets/images/empty-cart.jpg";

const Cart = ({ setOpenCart }) => {
  const { cart } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // console.log(cart);

  const removeFromCartHandler = (data) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(data));
  };

  const totalPrice = cart.reduce(
    (acc, item) => acc + item.qty * item.discountPrice,
    0
  );

  const quantityChangeHandler = (data) => {
    dispatch(addToCart(data));
  };
  return (
    <div className="fixed top-0 w-full left-0 h-screen z-10 bg-[#0000004b]">
      <div className="fixed top-0 right-0 min-h-full w-[25%] shadow-sm bg-white flex flex-col justify-between">
        {cart && cart.length === 0 ? (
          <div className="w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
            <div
              className={`flex w-full justify-end fixed pt-5 pr-5 top-3 right-3`}
            >
              <RxCross1
                size={25}
                className="cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => setOpenCart(false)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="text-center items-center  justify-center">
              <img
                src={EmptyCart}
                alt=""
                className="w-full h-min p-2 mb-2 object-cover"
              />
              <h5 className="font-semibold">Your cart is empty</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div>
              <div className="flex w-full justify-end pt-5 pr-5">
                <RxCross1
                  size={25}
                  className="cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={() => setOpenCart(false)}
                />
              </div>
              {/* Items length */}
              <div className={`${styles.normalFlex} p-4`}>
                <IoBagHandleOutline size={25} />
                <h5 className="pl-2 font-[500] text-[20px]">
                  {cart && cart.length} items
                </h5>
              </div>
              {/* cart single items */}
              <br />
              <div className="w-full border-t">
                {cart &&
                  cart.map((i, index) => (
                    <CartSingle
                      key={index}
                      data={i}
                      quantityChangeHandler={quantityChangeHandler}
                      removeFromCartHandler={removeFromCartHandler}
                    />
                  ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        )}

        <div className="px-5 mb-3">
          {/* Check Out Button */}
          <Link to={`/checkout`}>
            <div className="h-[45px] flex items-center justify-center w-[100%] bg-[#e44343] rounded-[5px]">
              <h1 className="text-[#fff] text-[15px] font-[600]">
                Checkout Now (USD ${totalPrice})
              </h1>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const CartSingle = ({ data, quantityChangeHandler, removeFromCartHandler }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(data.qty);
  const totalPrice = data.discountPrice * value;

  const increment = (data) => {
    if (data.stock < value) {
      toast.error(`Product Stock limited`);
    } else {
      setValue(value + 1);
      const updatecartData = { ...data, qty: value + 1 };
      quantityChangeHandler(updatecartData);
    }
  };
  const decrement = (data) => {
    setValue(value === 1 ? 1 : value - 1);
    const updatecartData = { ...data, qty: value === 1 ? 1 : value - 1 };
    quantityChangeHandler(updatecartData);
  };
  return (
    <div className="border-b p-4">
      <div className="w-full flex items-center">
        <div>
          <div
            className={`bg-[#e44343] border border-[#e4434373] rounded-full w-[25px] h-[25px] ${styles.normalFlex} justify-center cursor-pointer`}
            onClick={() => increment(data)}
          >
            <HiPlus size={18} color="#fff" />
          </div>
          <span className="pl-[10px]">{data.qty}</span>
          <div
            className="bg-[#a7abb14f] rounded-full h-[25px] flex items-center justify-center  cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => decrement(data)}
          >
            <HiOutlineMinus size={16} color="#7d879c" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <img
          src={data.images[0].url}
          alt=""
          className="w-[100px] h-min mr-2 rounded-[5px] object-cover ml-2"
        />
        <div className="pl-[5px]">
          <h1>{data.name}</h1>
          <h4 className="font-[400] text-[15px] text-[#00000082]">
            ${data.discountPrice}*{value}
          </h4>
          <h4 className="font-[600] text-[17px] pt-[3px] text-[#d02222] font-Roboto">
            US ${totalPrice}
          </h4>
        </div>
        <RxCross1
          className="cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(data)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

cart.js (reducer)

```js
import { createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  cart: localStorage.getItem(`cartItems`)
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`cartItems`))
    : [],
};

export const cartReducer = createReducer(initialState, {
  addToCart: (state, action) => {
    const item = action.payload;
    const isItemExist = state.cart.find((i) => i._id === item._id);
    if (isItemExist) {
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.map((i) => (i._id == isItemExist._id ? item : i)),
      };
    } else {
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: [...state.cart, item],
      };
    }
  },

  removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      cart: state.cart.filter((i) => i._id !== action.payload),
    };
  },
});
```

cart.js(actions)

```js
// add to cart
export const addToCart = (data) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: `addToCart`,
    payload: data,
  });
  localStorage.setItem(`CartItems`, JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cart));
  return data;
};

// remove from cart
export const removeFromCart = (data) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: `removeFromCart`,
    payload: data._id,
  });
  localStorage.setItem(`CartItems`, JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cart));
  return data;
};
```

Here are the screenshots or cart images before and after reloading

1. Before page reloading
   [1.Cart Image Before page reloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSl41.jpg)

2. After reloading page
   [2. cart image after reloading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpEap.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you are destructuring `cart` from  `useSelector` correctly ?

Comment: Yeah im destructuring it here is the snippet
```javascript

const Cart = ({ setOpenCart }) => {
  const { cart } = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // console.log(cart);
```